# Local unitary transformation that maximizes overlap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Could anyone point me in the right direction (reference to papers would suffice) regarding the following:

Given two quantum states $|\psi\rangle ,|\phi\rangle \in (\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$, where both states consists of $n$ subsystems of $d$ dimensions, what is the maximum  overlap I can achieve with local operations $U_{LU} = U_1 \otimes U_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes U_n$:

$$ 
\smash{\displaystyle\max_{U_{LU} \in \textrm{SU(d)} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathrm{SU(d)}}} \langle \phi|U_{LU}|\psi\rangle
$$.

If anyone knows of work on this or related topics, references would be appreciated.
I deal with states that are permutation symmetric (symmetric under exchange of subsystems), and that tends to simplify things.

For example has geometric entanglement measures been analytically calculated and proven for general permutation symmetric states (overlap with "closest" product state).

Before I finish, let me give an example (skipping normalization):

Let 
$$|\psi\rangle = |000\rangle + |111\rangle + |222\rangle, $$
 and 
$$|\phi\rangle = |012\rangle + |120\rangle +|201\rangle +|021\rangle + |102\rangle +|210\rangle
$$
be two tri-partite symmetric qutrit states. 
Maximum overlap is 2/3,  and is achieved by local quantum Fourier transform $U_{QFT} \otimes \cdots \otimes U_{QFT}$, acting on $|\psi\rangle$

Would be interesting to become friends with work attempting to find such solutions in more general an systematic manner.